# entropyfilt in OpenCV

Tags: image, matlab, opencv

I am working on an image processing project and I have to use [entopyfilt](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropyfilt.html) (from matlab).

I researched and found some information to do it but not enough. I can calculate the entropy value of an image, but I don't know how to write an entropy filter. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371053/findding-entropy-in-opencv/20377433#20377433) in the site, but I also didn't understand it.

Can anybody help me to understand entropy filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MATLAB documentation:

> J = entropyfilt(I) returns the array J, where each output pixel contains the entropy value   of the 9-by-9 neighborhood around the corresponding pixel in the input image I. I can have any dimension. If I has more than two dimensions, entropyfilt treats it as a multidimensional grayscale image and not as a truecolor (RGB) image. The output image J is the same size as the input image I.

For each pixel, you look at the 9 by 9 area around the pixel and calculate the entropy. Since the entropy calculation is a nonlinear calculation, it is not something you can do with a simple kernel filter. You have to loop over each pixel and do the calculation on a per-pixel basis.